# MVC Development Best Practice to represent database object and page model objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have MVC 3 web app where I get record(s) from DB which is used to render page elements and populate different partial views.

I have classes that represent these DB objects (service layer).

I have also separate set of classes which holds models get returned by the controllers to the view(s).

In my controller, I query DB that returns object to represent DB record.

Then I transfer (MAP) that DB Object to object that Represent the model used by the view(s)

**These classes are big and I have to write lots of code in the controller to map.**

**In most cases I only have some properties which are different.**

**It seems lots of extra work to do this mapping & lots of code to do the mapping**

**That is why I am asking.**

Is this the correct design approach of developing in MVC framework?

If no, then do you have some pointers that outline the best practice on this aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map between your DB objects and view models automatically.

Example:

```
SomeViewModel model = Mapper.Map<SomeViewModel>(someDbObj);
```

[Getting started guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: Hi Ben, If source class has 20 fields and I need 10 of them and 3 others need to be prepared combining other fields after the mapping is done, it is possible?

Comment: Sure, one you've performed the initial mapping you can do whatever you like with your object, even overriding properties that have already been mapped.

Answer (score 2):

The Model or ViewModel should only contain information that is used by the View. In some cases, this can be almost identical to what the objects you get from the database are,but this is not always the case. Keeping these concerns separate is good for a number of reasons beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer. On a side note, I hope you have a separate data access layer and am not querying the database , entity framework or service directly from the controller, again, just to keep those concerns separate.

Comment: I have service layer that talks to the database. DB concerns is isolated and separate.